# Using nock to mimic multiple couch db requests

Tags: node.js, couchdb, nock

In my original function I need to make 2 requests to 2 different db's within the same couch login.

```
var cloudant = require('cloudant')(https://cloudant_url);
var userdb = cloudant.db.use('user');
var addrdb = cloudant.db.use('address');

function onChange(username) {

    userdb.get(username, function(err,resp) {
        var user_id = resp.id;
        addrdb.get(user_id,function(err1,resp1){
            var addr = resp1.address;
        });
    });
};

var nockVar = function() {
nock(testCloudantDBURL)
    .get('/user/jack')
    .reply(200,{'id' : 123});

nock(testCloudantDBURL)
    .get('/address/123')
    .reply(200,{'address':'123});
};

describe('Test Cloudant Listener code' , function() {
    nockVar();

    it('test get scenario', function() {
        onChange('jack');
    });
});
```

With this only the first call works and I can get the id : 123. The second call on address db is not getting intercepeted.

With nock I'm able to intercept only the first call,the second call is not happening.Any pointers ?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your code is executed asynchronously and your test doesn't wait for the userdb.get and addrdb.get to finish. Easiest (not best) way to handle this is to add a done callback to your test scenario and call it as soon as your onChange function is finished. Roughly something like:

```
function onChange(username, done) {

    userdb.get(username, function(err,resp) {
        var user_id = resp.id;
        addrdb.get(user_id,function(err1,resp1){
            var addr = resp1.address;
            done();
        });
    };
};

    it('test get scenario', function(done) {
                onChange('jack', done);
        });
```

You might also consider working with Promises based code.